# Android Studio вылетает при открытии xml файлов

Tags: android-studio

Всех приветствую! На протяжении 3-х дней никак не могу решить проблему с Android Studio.
Недавно установил последнюю версию (на 2021.09.01) Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2. также перед установкой обновил Java, установил последнюю версию JDK, добавил системную переменную JAVA_HOME. Создал новый проект и как только открываю activity_main.xml - Android Studio закрывается, похоже на вылет. Весь yandex и google проштудировал - многие ответы указывают на изменение выделения памяти и переустановку Android Studio, ну-c...

После установки Android Studio, сразу отредактировал
studio64.exe.vmoptions

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

**В рабочем состоянии Memory Indicator показывает:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Диспетчер задач**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И всё равно, как только я открываю activity_main.xml через 2-5 секунд - Android Studio просто закрывается. Никаких ошибок, ничего - просто вылет.

**Я пробовал:**

- больше 10 раз переустанавливать Android Studio
- редактировать studio64.exe.vmoptions
- чистить кэш
- запускать от имени администратора

Буду очень признателен ответам. Спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68577130/16266470 попробуйте

Comment: @Pentiux, очень благодарен за ответ! Действительно, это работает!